# How to .map array elements which nested in another array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have array todos with elements which is also arrays and contain some numbers.

I need to *pass* through all arrays, how can I do this with ****.maps()**** ?

```js
todos = [
[23, 25],
[33, 36],
[55, 66],
]

console.log(todos.map(el => el.map(subEl => subEl)));
```

Comment: you mean need to combine all child array into one ? like `[23,25,33,36,55,66]`

Comment: No, I need to pass through all elements

Comment: But you *are* traversing through all elements... However, `map` is to be used for mapping. It it is just for passing through all elements, just use `for` loops (or `forEach`).

Comment: If you only want to go through them, then you can use foreach or for loops

Comment: but there is no solutions to do this with .map?

Comment: Do you need to create another array with it?

Comment: @AlexFlow you are nothing did on using map. you are just returning the argument

Answer (score 1):

Simply: `todos.flat().map(x => x)`

Answer (score 1):

you were pretty close but applied the function at the wrong point
I believe this is what you're looking for `console.log(todos.map(el => el.map(subEl => subEl)));`

```js
todos = [
[23, 25],
[33, 36],
[55, 66],
]

todos.map(el => el.map(subEl => console.log(subEl)));
```